# How does a service runs in the background - Android

Tags: android, service

I was asked this question in the interview today.

What is a service? 
To which I replied Service is basic component of Android which does  not have a UI and which runs in the background.

Does Service run on Main Thread ?
No

Then how does it run in background ?
.......

I was blank. Can someone please explain how does a service run in the background if it runs in the ui thread.

Thanks.

Comment: services run on the ui/main thread.

Comment: @Blackbelt u mean to say they dont run in background ?

Comment: in background means something else. I suppose what the documentation meant with *background* is the services' ability to run without user interaction and even if all the activities are paused

Comment: "A service is a component which runs in the background without direct interaction with the user. As the service has no user interface, it is not bound to the lifecycle of an activity." Taken fromthis tutorials: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: it's a copy/past of the documentation. Still it doesn't say that it spawns a different thread where the service will run

Comment: foreground : currently visible activity. Background : everything else. An Activity in the background is likely to be stopped at any moment by the system.

Comment: Just want to add that "in background" in this context is ambiguous. It can mean both: "run not in main thread" or "run without UI". Only latter is valid for `Service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service runs on UI Thread. To run a service task 'in background' you need in that service spawn a new Thread. 'In background' in context of a Service can be treated as 'can run without UI', but it doesn't mean it runs in its own thread.

Comment: hmm u r right. But still they should not have used the word "background"

Comment: What good does a Service do me, then, if it runs on the UI thread?
If i need to create a new thread anyhow, why won't I just create my thread on the main program and that's it?
What are the Benefits of a Service in this case?

Comment: Benefit of the service is the fact that it can run without a visible Activity (UI, View) so the user can leave your app and go to home screen and the operation will be still ongoing. When it finishes you will be able also to handle the result and for example store it somewhere. In case of running a Thread in an Activity an Activity will get destroyed and you will loose (or leak) the context that might lead to crashes / out of memory exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [official source](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics):

> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your
>   application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new
>   thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking
>   operations.

"UI thread" is just basically the main thread your app uses and that runs it's UI. It is not limited to running UI at all.