# How does a service operate internally in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, process

I understand that a Service runs in the background. I used the Service class before and I know its related methods. However, my question is related to the internal operations that correspond to running a service in the background.

From the documentation: ***"Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process."***

I also checked this question: [How does a service runs in the background - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277102/how-does-a-service-runs-in-the-background-android)

Does this mean that the the UI thread will keep operating and executing the task that the service is supposed to do? Can this be seen as running in the "Background of the app" Since the app tasks are run on the main thread by default and a service will run on that thread without a UI? Is that term correct? Or, "running in the Background of the OS" is more correct?

What if I used a Service (not an IntentService), then started a new thread inside that service would it also be seen as running in the background of the app or will that thread run in a different process and be seen as running in the background of the OS?

I'll appreciate it if someone can help me understand this concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as the UI thread.  Think of it as the Main thread.  Activities are objects that run on the main thread and have UIs.  They update those UIs on the main thread.  They have a complex lifecycle based around being on screen or not.  Services are objects that don't have a UI.  They have a much simpler lifecycle that's based around being started and stopped.  As such they will stick around (unless stopped) even if some other app owns the screen.

Neither of these things have anything to do with threading.  Either type of object can start a thread if it needs to, but unless they do so all processing will happen on the main thread of the application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is meant by the term "background" in the documentation, is it the background of an app or OS? Or, is it just to indicate that it doesn't have a UI? Also, if a service starts a thread, will that thread run inside the process of the app or in a different process? thank you.

Comment: All services are in the same process by default, so all threads launched by a service will be in the same process.  You can launch a service in a separate process, but in doing so you accept some limitations (such as needing to use IPC via aidl to bind to it).  If you do that, it will have its own main thread separate from the rest of the app.  But its not recommended unless you know what/why you're doing it.  Background as in the documentation means "without showing a UI" and indicates it continues to run no matter what is on screen.